# How can I extract a time partitioned table starting from a specific date with BigQuery API?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I need to extract a partitioned BQ table from a specific date.
The code below only extract the data at the specific partitioned day, how to adapt it in order to have all data from the specific date till now.
Thanks

```
def table_to_bucket(self):
        destination_uri = f"gs://{self.bucket_name}/mgi/{self.dataset_id}/{self.table_id}/*.avro"
        dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(source_project_id, self.dataset_id)
        
        job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig(print_header=True)
        job_config.destination_format = bigquery.DestinationFormat.AVRO
        job_config.compression = bigquery.job.Compression.SNAPPY

        if self.table.table_type == "TABLE":
            
            if self.table.time_partitioning and time_partition_argument == True:
                if self.table.time_partitioning.type_ == 'DAY':
                    table_id_date = f"{self.table_id}${date_day}"
                elif self.table.time_partitioning.type_ == 'MONTH':
                    table_id_date = f"{self.table_id}${date_month}"
                else:
                    print("error partinioning")
                table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id_date)

            else:
                table_ref = dataset_ref.table(self.table_id)
                
            try:
                extract_job = self.target_client.extract_table(table_ref, destination_uri, job_config=job_config, location="EU")
                extract_job.result()
                print(f"AVRO file exported to {destination_uri}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Comment: I've tried time range decorator (mytable@1655676000-1656280800) and got the error:
Time range decorator is not supported on partitioned or clustered tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible with the extract job API.  You can possibly script it yourself to run multiple extract jobs, or you can run an [export data query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_table_data) to select only the rows you care about (note that this export is billed as query, so it is not free).

Another alternative depending on the data size you can use the [Bigquery Storage Read API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) with a filter to stream data back and you can write it yourself (the best performance will come if you read Arrow data directly instead of converting it to python rows as shown in the linked example).

Comment: Thanks. I already use export data queries but I try to minimize my costs. I'll try the loop option but not sure of the velocity over x? days!

Comment: Note depending on data sizes you still might run into daily export limits.   You probably want to run them serially to avoid any contention.